# The backup or restore was aborted - what could it be?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2016, restore

```
use master
go
ALTER DATABASE Apcore SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE 

RESTORE DATABASE Apcore
FROM DISK=N'C:\Backups\QG-V-SQL-TS$AIFS_DEVELOPMENT_APCore_FULL_20180909_230034.bak'
WITH  FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'APCoreDataPrimary' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.DEVELOPMENT\MSSQL\DATA\APCoreDataPrimary.mdf',
MOVE N'APCoreData1' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.DEVELOPMENT\MSSQL\DATA\APCoreData1.ndf',
MOVE N'APCoreData_nonclusteredIndexes' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.DEVELOPMENT\MSSQL\DATA\APCoreData_nonclusteredIndexes.ndf',  
MOVE N'APCoreLog_log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.DEVELOPMENT\MSSQL\DATA\APCoreLog_log.ldf',  
recovery,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 1
```

[image]

While restoring a database on a developer's machine I got the above error.

The way I have done it is:

- First let me say that I did not worry about - permissions, indexes, triggers, synonyms, etc.
- I copied the backup file (less than 1 GB) from live to her local machine
- did the `restore filelestonly` which is ok
- I had to set the database into single_user mode because there are some services attempting to use it at every second
- prepared the script above, and when running it and got that error message.

what could it be?

[image]

Comment: Any jobs running to KILL long-running commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you have defined a command timeout when you connected to your server. Perhaps without thinking about it. Anyhow, the client (SSMS) will cancel the query after the specified amount of time and return that weird looking error of -2 (which wasn't thrown by the server, it is a client generates message). I tested this by connecting with the "Execution time-out" of 1 as in the picture below and then executed the SQL below.

[image]

```
SELECT 'before'
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
SELECT 'after'
```

Zero (0) means indefinitely.