# Why is my database restore being aborted?

Tags: sql-server, linux, sql-server-2017, azure

I'm trying to restore a SQL Server 2016 database into a SQL Server 2017 docker instance (`microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest`). The process seems to be:

1. Create docker container: `docker run -e ‘ACCEPT_EULA=Y’ -e ‘SA_PASSWORD=<strong password>’ -p 1433:1433 --name 'sql1' microsoft/mssql-server-linux`
2. Create backup directory: `docker exec -it sql1 mkdir /var/opt/mssql/backup`
3. Copy backup to directory: `docker cp Foobar.bak sql1:/var/opt/mssql/backup`
4. Login to mssql server: `mssql -o 1433 -u sa -p`
5. Get list of backed up files: `restore filelistonly from disk='/var/opt/mssql/backup/Foobar.bak'` <- each row returned will result in a `move` command in the next step
6. Restore database: `restore database Foobar from disk='/var/opt/mssql/backup/Foobar.bak' with stats=10, replace, move 'Foobar' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/Foobar.mdf', move 'Foobar_log' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/Foobar.ldf'`

The last step is failing with the output:

> Error: The backup or restore was aborted.

I tried to find an error log, and found `/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog`. AFAICT, nothing gets output in this file from my aborted restore operation.

How can I determine what is happening? Are there logs available that I can use to get more info?

Comment: Check this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/217157/the-backup-or-restore-was-aborted-what-could-it-be

Comment: Are you able to restore using `sqlcmd`?: `docker exec -it sql1 /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -Usa -P<strong password> -Q"restore database Foobar from disk='/var/opt/mssql/backup/Foobar.bak' with stats=10, replace, move 'Foobar' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/Foobar.mdf', move 'Foobar_log' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/Foobar.ldf';"`

Comment: @DanGuzman that worked! Thanks! If you write that up as an answer I'll mark it as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to execute any ad-hoc query within your container, including `RESTORE`, is with SQLCMD:

```
docker exec -it sql1 /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -Usa -P<strong password> -Q"restore database Foobar from disk='/var/opt/mssql/backup/Foobar.bak' with stats=10, replace, move 'Foobar' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/Foobar.mdf', move 'Foobar_log' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/Foobar.ldf';"
```